# Include PHP File in Smarty tpl

Tags: php, include, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I want to include a PHP script that outputs some HTML in productdetail-full.tpl file (Smarty / Prestashop 1.6.x)

I tried:

```
{php}
   include('show-stock-pos.php');
{/php}
```

AND

```
{include_php 'show-stock-pos.php'}
```

But they are both deprecated. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write smarty plugin and then in plugin function include desired file, then you will not break depreced method.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SmartyBC - Backwards Compatibility Wrapper` for this since it's not recommended using php code in the templates.

Instead of:

```
require_once('path/to/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

Use:

```
require_once('path/to/smarty/libs/SmartyBC.class.php');
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

And  you will be able to use PHP in your Smarty template files.

More info about this here:

https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop is a modular system that uses hooks to display information.

According to Prestashop standards and solutions, you should use hooks and module:

1. Generate new module with a custom hook (or Use the available hook in the Productdetail-full.tpl file)
2. Get content of your PHP file in your module (using curl for example)
3. Pass your content to smarty
4. display content in your Hook

Comment: Why you have mentionated Prestashop in this context?

Comment: @Payedimaunt Question has Prestashop tag